# Vista 64 automatically hibernates after resuming from hibernate

Tags: windows-vista, hibernate

I have Windows Vista 64 running on a Dell XPS 420. I hibernate Vista instead of shutting down. When I power back on, if I don't press a key or move the mouse then a minute after powering on it will automatically hibernate. My power settings say to never hibernate or sleep.

Any idea why it is automatically hibernating when it starts up?

Answer (score 6):

It also happens on my computer with XP SP3. See the section *The Computer Hibernates After Resume* in [this document](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5590836.html) for an explanation:

> After your computer resumes from
>   hibernation, it may enter hibernation
>   again after five minutes of
>   inactivity, regardless of the settings
>   you have configured in the Power
>   Options tool in Control Panel. This
>   occurs if the computer's BIOS resets
>   itself as the computer resumes from
>   hibernation and clears any wakeup
>   signals that might be active.
>   Therefore, the operating system cannot
>   determine why the computer woke up and
>   as such returns to hibernation after
>   five minutes of inactivity. It does so
>   to avoid situations where an
>   application wakes up the computer and
>   causes the battery to drain while the
>   computer is not being used.

In other words, it's not a bug, it's a feature... Well, I would agree if it was possible to turn this behaviour off, but there seems to be no way except to reconfigure your BIOS, which in my case is not possible  :-(